# How much is a cup of graham cracker crumbs in crackers and weight?

Tags: measurements, crumb-crust

I have a recipe that calls for one cup of graham cracker crumbs.   How many crackers am I going to need to crush?

I'm having trouble finding an answer partly because different people consider a "cracker" to be of various sizes.  I would consider a cracker to be a full sized sheet like this:

[image] ([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aGraham_cracker.jpg))

It would also be helpful to know what a cup of graham cracker crumbs weighs.   My box of crackers is 14.4oz.   I could estimate what portion of the box to use if I know how much a cup of crumbs weighs.

Comment: Perhaps the most useful advice long-term would be to look for recipes which use weight rather than volume.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be about 7 crackers per cup, maybe 8, depending how finely you crush them. One of the inner packages from your 14.4oz box should be plenty (there are probably three packages with 9 in each, or 4.8oz). If you need to go the other way, that's 1/7 to 1/8 cup per cracker, or more simply, 0.5oz or 15g per cracker.

I know this from making graham cracker crusts - and you can confirm it by looking at some recipes. You generally need 1.5 cups of crumbs for a pie crust, and it takes 10-12 crackers. I've seen recipes ranging from 9 to 12 crackers (and checked ten or so when writing this), but I don't think I've ever used fewer than 10. One cup is 2/3 of that, 7 or 8 crackers. (Some people do say 20 or 24 squares, but they're clearly half-cracker squares, not the whole crackers.)

For what it's worth, the Martha Stewart crust recipe says "6 1/2 ounces graham crackers (12 crackers), finely ground (1 1/2 cups)", and 2/3 of that is 4 1/3 oz, pretty close to 1/3 of your box, maybe a cracker short, so by weight this works out too.

Answer (score 4):

(I don't care that this thread is old, I was looking for this answer and this was one of the top three Google results.)

I just pulverized 8 full sheets (Honey Maid, 8 sheets come per wax paper package, 3 of those per box), which resulted in a scant 1 1/2 C of crumbs (just shy of 1 1/2 C, more than 1 1/4 C.)  Those 8 sheets netted approximately 4.9 oz of crumb according to my scale.

Answer (score 3):

According to culinary school 1 C Graham Crackers is 85 grams, and from package of graham crackers

- 8 crackers (2 sheets) are 31 grams.
- so ONE cup should be 5 1/2 sheets (22 cracker).
- To make 1 1/2 cups, you need 33 crackers ( 8 sheets and a quarter)..
- To make 2 cups, you need 44 crackers (11 sheets)....

**Revised by [Chef_Code](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/34383/chef-code)**
Answers may vary depending on crumb size of the graham crackers as well as if you pack down the cup, because of the possibility of these variables weight to volume as well as volume to weight conversion results may vary.  all answers above are close but are still to be considered approximate.  Here is a [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=y_B2j8b-9icC&pg=PA62&dq=The%20book%20of%20Yields,%20graham%20crackers&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BQYuVbatO4nkoAS-yoGwDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=The%20book%20of%20Yields%2C%20graham%20crackers&f=false) for more information on the math.  If the link breaks in the future here is an additional [link](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0471745901)

Comment: @Chef_Code I don't think an edit like that is appropriate in a non-wiki answer. It also doesn't seem to be particularly useful information. The original poster was just looking for an estimate of number crackers that need to be crushed, not a precise amount, so it doesn't need be pointed out this answer can only be an approximation.

Comment: @RossRidge, the information added is both appropriate and useful. That said, it could have been added as a comment rather than as part of the edit. Either way, it is good information for novice cooks/bakers.

Comment: @Cindy There's a ton of good and relevant information for novices that could be added to every post on this site. In the context of answering this question the edit doesn't improve the post. And why does only this answer get singled out? If it's useful and appropriate for this post, it should should also be useful and appropriate for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly it should be 4.8 ounces of 27 graham crackers or 1 pack of this [brand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016510LG). I did a little bit of a back calculation using this [recipe](http://www.oprah.com/food/Graham-Crust-Recipe).

Calculation:

190 gms is equivalent to 1.5 cups, so 1 cup should have 127gms which is equivalent to 4.48 ounces and almost close to a pack of 4.8 ounces but if you want accuracy then you need 25 crackers of the brand that I mentioned in [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016510LG)

Answer (score 1):

Graham crackers are definitely smaller than they used to be when I was growing up. For my recipe, I used Honey Maid from the 14.4 ounce box containing 3 packs with 9 crackers in each. I followed the first answer I saw -- 10 crackers -- and it was just short of the 1.5 cups of crumbs I needed.  I had to crush 2 more crackers to get 1.5 cups.

So, for Honey Maid:

- 4 crackers = 1/2 cup
- 8 crackers = 1 cup
- 12 crackers = 1.5 cups

Answer (score 0):

10 graham crackers equals 1 and 1/2 cups so about 7 or 8 should equal 1 cup.

Comment: 2/3 of 10 is 6 to 7, not 7 to 8. But I suspect you're ending up with them a bit more fluffy than I do.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran one inner package of graham crackers through the food processor. It made 1 1/4 cups of crumbs. So, an entire box (14.4 oz) will yield approx. 3 3/4 cups of crumbs. I suggest you you run an entire box of crackers through the food processor and store in an air tight container and measure what you need, when you need it.

Comment: How many crackers were in that inner pack for you?

Answer (score 0):

20 SQUARES--crushed==1½ cups--I just did this for a recipe today.