# Measurement for 3 sheets of crushed graham cracker

Tags: baking

My receipe calls for 3 sheets of crushed graham cracker. I bought pre-crushed graham cracker. What is the cup measurement for 3 crushed sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Jefromi answered this related question [How much is a cup of graham cracker crumbs in crackers and weight?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45327/how-much-is-a-cup-of-graham-cracker-crumbs-in-crackers-and-weight) with the information that there are 7 or 8 crushed crackers in a cup. So, 3 crackers would be about .4 cup crushed.

Comment: I'm closing as a duplicate, because there is really no sense in answering it for 1 cup, 2 cups, 3 cups... etc. once the ratio has been established.