# Graham Cracker Sheets

Tags: baking

Please tell me what are Graham Cracker Sheets? I live in Australia and have not heard of them but I'm sure we have an equivalent, any advice appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! See this: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50371/is-there-a-super-close-substitute-for-graham-crackers and this: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45327/how-much-is-a-cup-of-graham-cracker-crumbs-in-crackers-and-weight The picture in the second question is of a graham cracker sheet. If you are trying to make a specific recipe, we can probably be of more help if you post the recipe or at least what you want to do with the crackers. Without more info, this question is likely to be closed as a duplicate of the first question I listed...

Comment: But don't let it bother you if that happens. It only means that someone else asked the same good question first.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been told by a relative, Australia doesn't really have an equivalent of Graham Crackers. Given how rarely you can find them at the import stores, you're best off making your own. I use [this recipe at King Arthur Flour](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/graham-crackers-recipe).
 I like it because the measurements are adaptable between volumes and weights, so the recipe can work in any country. Any quality brand name of flour will work. It doesn't have to be KAF brand.

Answer (score 0):

A rough equivalent for graham cracker sheets might be a sheet of gingerbread. Graham is very similar to gingerbread; generally less sweet, less spiced and with some more rough grind of wheat (the "graham flour").

Another similar item would be McVitie's original digestive biscuits - http://www.manassen.com.au/Product-Detail.asp?CategoryID=77&ProductID=7542&SubProductID=136
Graham cracker is a little bit sweeter, with less bran and therefore crisper.

And if you want to go all out for the real thing, take a look here: http://www.usafoods.com.au/search?keywords=graham
Choose one of the products described as "honey" - not "cinnamon".

Take care: the real graham crackers are very hydrophilic and they will spoil quickly after opening!